# How to show values in comboBox, I am getting "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I want custid(column) from customer(table) in combo box, but it does not shows custid values but "System.Data.DataRowView" for every value. I am working on asp.net, using comboBox from ajax toolkit any mysql (wamp server).

```
    string cs2 = "Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;Uid=root;Password=;";
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(cs2);
    cn.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter Mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select custid from customer", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Mda.Fill(ds, "customer");
    ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["customer"];
    ComboBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: As I mentioned I am using combo box from Ajax toolkit which does not provide ValueMember, DisplayMember attribute. and other suggestions in that posts are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `DataTextField` and/or `DataValueField`-attributes:

```
<cc1:ComboBox 
     DataTextField="custid"
     DataValueField="custid" 
     runat="server">
```

For a full example take a look at: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/combobox/how-do-i-use-the-combobox-control-cs

Comment: Thank you very much, finally it works. May Allah Almighty bless you =)